# Javascript closure VS dojo lang.hitch

Tags: javascript, dojo, closures

Which is best practice, which results in better performance?

using closure or dojo.lang.hitch ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `lang.hitch(scope, method)` returns a closure, i.e. it returns a function, which will call function `method` in the given `scope`. That's useful especially when defining callbacks in object oriented code, so you can write:

```
on(dom.byId("button"), "click", lang.hitch(this, "callback"));
```

instead of:

```
on(dom.byId("button"), "click", function(scope, method) {
    return function() {
        method.apply(scope);
    }
}(this, this["callback"])); // execute the anonymous function immediately to get a closure
```

Something like this will work:

```
on(dom.byId("button"), "click", this["callback"]);
```

but `this` inside the `callback` method will point to the `button`.

See the complete code with additional details in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/r7jLr/